# Unable to find element with xpath within nested framesets

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

I'm using `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@title='A K T İ V A S Y O N']"));` to locate the element given below in the screenshots but getting `Unable to find element` error.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

There are nested classes and frames also. how can I use switch method for nested frames?

My last try is the following one; Screenshot's attached also.[image]

> driver.findElement(By.xpath("//frameset[@id='fset1']//frame[@name='ax']//frame[@name='menu']//div[@id='vodaMenuDiv']//li[@id='CCBmain']//li[@id='ccbabone']//li[@id='ccbcquery']//a[@title='A
>   K T İ V A S Y O N']")).click();

Comment: Check if the element is inside iframe

Comment: Try xpath using contains text-    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//a[contains(text(),'A K T İ V A S Y O N')]"));

Comment: You can also try this may this work for you- driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//li[@id='ccbcquery']/a"));

Answer (score 0):

Use below alternatives to locate the element-

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@id='ccbcquery']/a")).click();
```

equivalent css selector is

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("li[id='ccbcquery']>a")).click();
```

OR

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("li#ccbcquery>a")).click();
```

**Pointed to be noted**

1. Make sure element is not in frame if yes then switch into respective frame using `driver.switchTo().frame(frameid/element);` and then perform action
2. Use implicit/explicit wait to get element proper load and available in DOM

   ```
   driver.get("web_irl");
   driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
   ```

   Explicit Wait :

   ```
   new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("li#ccbcquery>a")))).click();
   ```

Comment: It is about frames (not iframes), voting down to push better answers up. Feel free to edit (and tag me in a comment to vote up again) or delete your answer.

Comment: @NielsvanReijmersdal, thanks for suggestion, I have updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot find an element, you need to check if it is inside a frame (or iframe). A [frameset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/frameset) is a way to split a window in multiple frames, which acts as a separate window. Selenium needs to switch to this frame first before you can find elements in it.

Your last image shows that the element is within multiple framesets and frames. As frames are not part of the page, but a sort of page on it own you first need to switch to the frame and then to frame within before you can find the element.

Check out some reads:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15464808/how-to-navigate-a-subframe-inside-a-frameset-using-selenium-webdriver
- https://www.swtestacademy.com/selenium-webdriver-frames/

Answer (score 0):

By using:
https://github.com/nick318/FindElementInFrames

You can write:

```
SearchByFramesFactory searchFactory = new SearchByFramesFactory(driver);
searchFactory.search(() -> driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@title='A K T İ V A S Y O N']"))).getElem();
```

It will find your element across any iframes.

Comment: I believe the good answer would not be just promoting your library but also give a quick guide on how to apply it to address OP's particular issue.

Comment: @AlexeyR updated, thank you